# How to disable the click for Mondays in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I need help with FullCalendar. I want to disable specified days, for example, all Mondays of the month, and just allow to click all other days except for Mondays.

I already have this code, to prevent user from selecting old days. So I need a way to disable click on all Mondays (or Fridays, etc).

```
function (pOptions) {

    pOptions.weekNumberCalculation= 'ISO';
    pOptions.weekNumbers = false;
    pOptions.weekNumberTitle = "W";
    pOptions.selectAllow = function (info) {
        if (info.start.isBefore(moment().add(-1,'days')))
            return false;
        return true;
    };
    return pOptions;
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/businessHours and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/selectConstraint

Comment: P.S. I fail to see what this has to do with Oracle or apex...it appears to be a fullCalendar and JavaScript question

Comment: The Calendar in Apex is FullCalendar

Comment: Ok. But those technologies are not involved in the solution to the problem, therefore they are not relevant to the question, and should not be tagged.